# Are these app permissions normal?

Tags: applications, security, permissions

Can it be used to steal personal data or intercept/view online activity?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apps with Storage permission (Read the contents of SD card) can read all of your personal data in `/sdcard` i.e. photos, documents, music , downloaded data etc.

Comment: @IrfanLatif what about viewing online activity?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you. This app well required Storage permission for Download files for your app new levels but if you think if i get permission and your (personal & private)data leak then you can not do to access permission. 
they well risky for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nope
Beware check if you're phone 
Can manage to shout down and start upp
According to you're settings
If it won't start then you're not alone